# How to show a Dialog in WPF with only one button?

Tags: wpf, dialog

I want to Show a wpf view in my application as a Dialog. For this, I'm using the method showDialog from System.Windows.

So far, everything is fine. The Dialog appears and Shows my view. But there are two Buttons (OK, Cancel).

I only want the OK button to be visible. Is there a way to influence the showDialog method like you can with MessageBox.Show() ?

Comment: `ShowDialog` is just a method to show a window with control, which disables parent window till the dialog returns control. What the dialog has as its content is just your business.